# How to list buckets from Google Storage in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have the following code in Python script:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'JSON_AUTH_FILE'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE
```

This does the auth with google.

Now I want to list all buckets :

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)
```

But this doesn't work. I get:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403

xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project
```

It also has a link when I click it i see (which is weird because it says 403 but here it shows 401:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.list access to project NUMBER.",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.list access to project NUMBER."
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have a `sqlservice.admin` scope if you're trying to access Cloud Storage?

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso I don't know. This is the first time I'm working with Google. This is what their guide showed in the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things to suggest in reference to this link:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

There are a couple of ways you can set roles for service accounts to access Google Storage:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud_storage_roles

#### Using a default role when creating a service account

When you create your service account, select the **Project Role: Storage -> Storage Admin**. Setting this role will allow your service account to access and manipulate objects from Cloud Storage. Using the **Storage Admin** role ensures that you give the least amount of privilege to the service account so that it can't access other services.

If you're having problems with authentication perhaps look at setting the role to **Project -> Editor** which should give the service account edit access to most of the GCP services. Just be aware that if the service account is compromised the user will have access to most of your services in the GCP project.

#### Using a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) to inherit multiple roles

By setting a custom role you can inherit the permissions given to a number of the default roles. A good way to do this is by using the **"Create Role From Selection"** in the [IAM & Admin -> Roles](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles) section of the GCP Console.

For example you could combine the **BigQuery Admin** and **Storage Object Admin** into a single custom role by selecting the check-boxes for each role and creating your own custom role which you can then allocate to your service account in the [IAM section of GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam).

---

Once you have a service account with the correct permissions you should be able set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable and use the [`google`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) library to access your storage buckets.

Try this modification to your code once you have a service account with the correct role to test to see if it can [list all the buckets](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.list_buckets) the account has access to

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"

# Instantiates a client
storage_client = storage.Client()

# List all the buckets available
for bucket in storage_client.list_buckets():
    print(bucket)
```

Comment: How do I change it for existing service account? I can't find this menu. There is only : edit / delete / create key and edit offer only changing the name

Comment: Say instead of listing buckets I want to upload file. Would I still need to change the Role? Because I actually need to upload files... the listing objects is just a test.

Comment: I usually just create a new service account when I need to add new roles. You'll be able to upload files using the Storage Object Admin because it has read and write permissions to the bucket

Comment: You can just create another account (you can create as many as you would like). If you're not using one that you've created you can just delete it.

Comment: The current role is Big Query editor.. If I change it to  Storage Object Admin does it means I won't have permissions over big query?!

Comment: Have a look at this link https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts

Comment: yeah I found it. But my question is why can't a member have more than 1 role? Basicly I need a member for Storage and a member for BigQuery? then make 2 auth requests? Sounds weird.

Comment: You should be able to add a separate role so that you can have permission to access BigQuery and Cloud Storage

Comment: That I got. I'm asking if the same one can have permissions on both? My script add file to Storage and then continue to work over big query.

Comment: Ah ok I think I figured it out. You'll need to create a custom role. In the custom role you can select the different GCP permissions that you require.

Comment: how do I make my role custom?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#viewing_the_available_permissions_for_a_resource

Comment: by the way I used ur code change the permission as you suggested and I still get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174178/discussion-between-jack-and-scottmcc).

Comment: Everything is set but your code gives the same error.

Comment: I've added some additional information for setting service account roles in an edit to my answer. Perhaps look at setting the role to `Project -> Editor` first to see if you can authenticate correctly. Then if that works maybe look to create a custom role with only the permissions that you need to access Google Cloud Storage and BigQuery

Comment: Also I have made a previous mistake in my answer. You need to use `Storage Admin` not `Storage Object Admin` to list the buckets. The `Storage Object Admin` role didn't have the `storage.buckets.list` permission.

Comment: Changing it to Storage Admin fixed it. Now it works!

Comment: Great! We got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like this:

```
    import os
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    from google.cloud import storage

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/test-path-to-your-file/file.json')
    storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)

    # List all the buckets available (@ScottMcC code)
    for bucket in storage_client.list_buckets():
       print(bucket)
    
    #or you can list it
    list(storage_client.list_buckets())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Storage Admin not Storage Object Admin to list the buckets. The Storage Object Admin role didn't have the storage.buckets.list permission.all credit goes to  ScottMcC for the excellent answer.